# Posting Questions with Answer

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, self-answer

Can I post questions while immediately giving an answer, when I think it is important enough to share?

I guess this is not the original spirit of Stack Exchange, though sometimes I think it would be good to have it saved somewhere. Also for myself in the case I might forget the answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

Take a look at [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) that explains the thinking behind it.

It's even encouraged on the 'Ask Question' page with a checkbox of "Answer your own question". Granted you cannot self accept your answer for a few days to allow for possible better answers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, and indeed if you intend to self answer you should. If you don't do this you'll have to wait before posting your own answer.

There's even a check box at the bottom of the post for you to tick:

> [image]

When you do you get an answer box straight away:

> [image]