# "Edit must be at least 6 characters" - but I am retagging!

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

**Edit**: it happens again with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250424/whole-comment-area-clickable) question. I am trying just to add [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), but it says that "Edits must be at least 6 chars". That's certainly a bug. Earlier today I [submitted a retagging edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37699) successfully.

---

> [image]

I changed [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to [support](/questions/tagged/support) in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234341/posting-questions-with-answer), but can't submit my edit. Why?

Comment: You sure you didn't make an unintentional edit there?

Comment: @Oded Yes, I reloaded page, no effect.

Comment: Read the post ... surely you can get to 6 characters.

Comment: You don't have retag rights so your retag is a suggested edit instead - which needs 6 characters.

Comment: @ChrisF Usually I can retag without editing body. Suggest retags.

Comment: How many characters was that edit I just made? Surely you could at least find a few more things to fix.

Comment: You people are missing the point of this post. [Simple retags are usually allowed in suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5109709), but the system is preventing it here for some reason. Whether or not the edit is actually useful might be worth mentioning, but not something you should get stuck on.

Comment: @Oded Ok. I just [suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29225) a just retagging edit on another question.

Comment: @Oded And anonymous user just suggested retag on my question which I approved.

Comment: @ChrisF Read above comments too.

Comment: When I see this it's usually because I somehow added an extra space or otherwise modified the content in the body (even if I later reverted my change).  If you discard your edit and try to re-edit, being careful to only change the tag, do you still get the error message?

Comment: @Troyen Currently it permits. Maybe because it was edited since I asked my question (it was, by Doorknob).

Comment: @Oded This kind of bug has happened before, where the backend was doing some kind of whitespace or Unicode normalization and this got counted as part of the edit even though no modification was apparent.

Comment: @Gilles - very possible. Was trying to ascertain if other things were afoot.