# Whole comment area clickable?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

> iPad, iOS App ver.1.2.2

Instead of clicking the very tiny "..." button next to the comments so to show the comment action menu:

[image: .]

Is it possible to change something so that the menu gets brought up when you click anywhere inside the area of a comment, not just the little nearly-unclickable button?

Comment: Is that in one of the smartphone apps? Which one?

Comment: @Gilles obviously iOS app. Can't you look at the screenshot closer? ;)

Comment: @nicael I thought it would be iOS since it doesn't look like Android, but is it the iPhone app or the iPad app?

Comment: @Gilles Look at the top bar on the screen shot :) What do you see?

Comment: @nicael I see a bunch of indistinct icons and perhaps text on the left, in the middle and on the right. Maybe there's something there that iDevice users would recognize, but I don't.

Comment: @Gilles "iPad" at the top left corner.

Comment: @nicael If you say so. I can't actually make out the letters, though what I can see is consistent with “iPad”.

Comment: @Gilles also iPhone would have a thicker top bar relative to the other content.

Comment: Actually this is already done in the iOS app for iPhone, version 1.2.2.194, what version you have?

Comment: V1.2.2 @ShadowWizard

Comment: So it means you're using the official build, not beta channel... it would be live when they push new build to app store.

Comment: how do you use the beta channel then? @ShadowWizard

Comment: You need to be invited by the iOS app dev team, I'm trying to ask around if it's still possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah. I see. Thank you!

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 you can sign up [with this link](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform). I'll send out invites on Monday.

Comment: I'll check with Kasra about this. We originally used the right tab because comment links were virtually untappable on an iPad mini. Links now have a bigger tap area and we are adding a less intrusive comment toolbar so why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be in the next build. We had the three dots for two reasons:

1. Links in comments were hard to tap, on all devices but especially on iPad minis.  **This is no longer an issue as we've [increased the hit radius for comment links to match web views](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel/pull/480).**
2. If you missed the link, you would have to dismiss the menu and try tapping the link again.  This would get truly frustrating.  **We've replaced the popover with a toolbar that appears on tap and does not interfere as much with what you're doing.**

Since both these issues are gone:

```diff
--- a/Stack Exchange/SECommentTableViewCell.m   
+++ b/Stack Exchange/SECommentTableViewCell.m   
@@ -60,7 +60,7 @@

 + (BOOL)handlesSelectionInternally
 {
-    return SERunningPhablet() || SERunningTablet();
+    return NO;
 }
```

Comment: god bless america.